# How to group similar elements in an array with less complexity?

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, machine-learning

Assume we have a rectangular array which integer values like this:

```
A = [[1,1,2,2,2],
     [1,2,2,2,1],
     [1,3,3,3,1]]
```

How to group the same integer values which are connected each other to different clusters? Cluster size is **unknown**.

Required output (Different clusters of the same integer which are connected each other):

```
Group 1 : A[0,0],A[0,1],A[1,0],A[2,0]
Group 2 : A[0,2],A[0,3],A[0,4],A[1,1],A[1,2],A[1,3]
Group 3 : A[1,4],A[2,4]
Group 4 : A[2,1],A[2,2],A[2,3]
```

Which is the most suitable algorithm for doing the same.
Is it possible to use machine learning for this problem?

Comment: Why `A[1,4],A[2,4]` are not in first group or `A[2,0]`? And have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What you mean by *based on adjustment cells*? Pls add more explanation to your question or the code that you've tried so far.

Comment: @Kasramvd adjacent cells (type error )

Comment: Because We are grouping based on adjacent cells. There is no cells (In this case 1) which connects group 1 and group 3

Comment: You should add a picture of the matrix that A represents, as a grid, with the numbers inside it. A picture speaks a thousand words.

Comment: Question is not clear. What are the numbers in `A`? Are they integers? What is the similarity metric? What is the output? What is `a`?

Comment: @CentAu Please review now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any graph searching algorithm ([BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)) will do.

Vertices of the graph are the elements of the matrix, and edges exist between adjacent elements, so each vertex has 2 to 4 neighbors.

Create an auxiliary matrix of the same size which will store the number of cluster for each element, and some other value (e.g. -1) for elements which are not yet in any cluster.
Now, to obtain the clusters, loop over all elements of the matrix.
When you find an element which is not yet in any cluster, run a BFS or DFS from it to find its connected component of equal values, marking all these values in the auxiliary matrix by the number of the new cluster.

The complexity is O (number of elements), the same as to just read or write the matrix.